# Returning value from one column conditional on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have a wide `data.frame` representing observations on rows and time periods on columns. I have two variables `A` and `B` in `10` time periods each. Variable `A` is binary and variable `B` is continuous.

I'd like to create a new column in the data frame that returns, by row, the value of `B` that corresponds to the first time `A == 1`, making sure to ignore `NA`s and go on to the next column if 1 is not reached (I imagine something with `na.rm=TRUE`).

Here's the data (using just 3 time periods and not 10, and this is very rare ):

```
structure(list(A.1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
A.2 = c(1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), A.3 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA), B.1 = c(63L, 58L, 87L, 
60L, 67L, 58L, 67L, 50L, 77L, 57L, 57L, 65L, 55L, 65L, 61L, 
61L, 67L, 75L, 79L, 68L, 53L, 73L, 77L, 77L, 69L), B.2 = c(64L, 
NA, 88L, 63L, NA, 59L, NA, NA, 79L, 58L, 58L, 66L, 57L, 67L, 
62L, 62L, 68L, 77L, 80L, NA, NA, 74L, 78L, 78L, NA), B.3 = c(NA, 
NA, 90L, NA, NA, 60L, NA, NA, NA, 59L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 63L, 
NA, 69L, NA, 82L, NA, NA, NA, 79L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("A.1", 
"A.2", "A.3", "B.1", "B.2", "B.3"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 34L, 
36L, 44L, 46L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 58L, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

The final column should return `63` for the first value and `NA` for the second and `90` for the third, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: `with(df1, df1[A == 1, B ])` Here `df1` is your data frame. I am not sure how your wide data frame looks like. Please post a sample of your data using `dput(df1)`

Comment: `with(df1, df1[ (!is.na(A)) & A == 1, ])`

Comment: There's not a single `A ==1` in your data, also give us your expected output, that makes our life much easier and will help you to come up with sample data that makes sense

Comment: Apologies, the data is very scarce and more of the 1s in the "A" variable occur later on. Hope this helps! (still new at this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with `apply` :

```
df1$C <-
  apply(df1,1,function(x){
    i <- match(1,head(x,length(x)/2))
    if (length(i)) tail(x,length(x)/2)[i] else NA
  })

df1
#    A.1 A.2 A.3 B.1 B.2 B.3  C
# 1    1   1  NA  63  64  NA 63
# 3    0  NA  NA  58  NA  NA NA
# 4    0   0   1  87  88  90 90
# 8    0   0  NA  60  63  NA NA
# 10   0  NA  NA  67  NA  NA NA
# 11   0   0   0  58  59  60 NA
# 14   0  NA  NA  67  NA  NA NA
# 15   0  NA  NA  50  NA  NA NA
# 16   0   0  NA  77  79  NA NA
# 18   0   0   0  57  58  59 NA
# 21   0   0  NA  57  58  NA NA
# 23   0   0  NA  65  66  NA NA
# 25   0   1  NA  55  57  NA 57
# 27   0   0  NA  65  67  NA NA
# 29   0   0   0  61  62  63 NA
# 34   0   0  NA  61  62  NA NA
# 36   0   0   0  67  68  69 NA
# 44   0   0  NA  75  77  NA NA
# 46   0   0   0  79  80  82 NA
# 51   0  NA  NA  68  NA  NA NA
# 52   0  NA  NA  53  NA  NA NA
# 53   0   0  NA  73  74  NA NA
# 55   0   0   0  77  78  79 NA
# 58   0   0  NA  77  78  NA NA
# 60   0  NA  NA  69  NA  NA NA
```

if you have other columns in your table this won't work, but just replace `head(x,length(x)/2))` by `x[A_indices]` (e.g. `x[3:12]`) and `tail(x,length(x)/2))` by `x[B_indices]` (e.g. `x[13:22]`) and it should work.

And for comparison here's a `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
Cs <- df1 %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%
  gather(,,-1) %>%
  separate(key,c("letter","number")) %>%
  spread(letter,value) %>%
  filter(A==1) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(rowid,C=B)

df1$C <- NA
df1$C[Cs$rowid] <- Cs$C
```

Comment: thank you! That works perfectly! Apologies for the rough start!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution man:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  new <- (((test[i, 4:6] [grepl(x=test[i, 1:3],pattern= "1")])))
  test[i, "new"] <- ifelse(dim(new)[2] == 1, new[[1]], NA)
}
```

Please adjust the column indices accordingly. Excuse me for a bit of a  messy code as I was already in a rush but could not stop thinking about your problem.

Hopefully, my code helps you get the required results.

Have a good one and cheers,

Jatin.